# Excel Return Multiple Unique Values

Tags: excel-formula

I'm using this formula:

```
INDEX($A:$A;RANDBETWEEN(1;COUNTA($A:$A));1)
```

to return values from a column to a cell. It works fine, but I need to return 4 values total, and I need all of them to be unique. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a formula like this:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$26)/(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$A$1:$A$26)=0),RANDBETWEEN(1,ROWS(A1:A26)-ROW(1:1)+1)))
```

With your local settings:

```
=INDEX(A:A;AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW($A$1:$A$26)/(COUNTIF($C$1:C1;$A$1:$A$26)=0);RANDBETWEEN(1;ROWS(A1:A26)-ROW(1:1)+1)))
```

Since this does refer to the cells above the formula it must be placed in the second or lower row and the `$C$1:C1` must refer to the cell directly above the first instance of the formula.

Then drag it down 4 times.

[image]

---

Aggregate is an array formula type.  The references should only include those of the data set.  Full column references should be avoided as it will force the Aggregate to do more calculations than needed, and will return blanks in this specific case.

To automatically include only the data set, grow or shrink depending on the data in column A, use this:

```
=INDEX(A:A;AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A;MATCH("zzz";A:A)))/(COUNTIF($C$1:C1;$A$1:INDEX(A:A;MATCH("zzz";A:A)))=0),RANDBETWEEN(1;ROWS($A$1:INDEX(A:A;MATCH("zzz";A:A)))-ROW(1:1)+1)))
```

---

Edit #1

To drag to the right use this:

```
=INDEX($A:$A;AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A;MATCH("zzz",$A:$A)))/(COUNTIF($B$2:B2;$A$1:INDEX($A:$A;MATCH("zzz";$A:$A)))=0);RANDBETWEEN(1;ROWS($A$1:INDEX($A:$A;MATCH("zzz";$A:$A)))-COLUMN(A:A)+1)))
```

And change the `$B$2:B2` to the cell directly left of the first placement of the formula.

[image]

Comment: Instead of dragging it down 4 times, can I drag it right? The source data is in a column but the resulting data needs to be in different (adjacent)columns.

Comment: I translated the formula into Turkish, but I'm getting (#NUM!) error after the first cell. Trying to figure it out.

Comment: What Excel are you using?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using: 2010,2007,2013, Office 365?

Comment: Excel says Office 365 Proplus.

Comment: Be careful with what is and what is not absolute.  Make sure the `$` match mine.

Comment: Finally! Thanks! My bad, I misread ROWS as ROW. This was a great help, and possibly the longest formula I've ever seen. Thanks so much.

Comment: For anyone who might be interested, here is the Turkish version:
`=İNDİS($A:$A;TOPLAMA(15;6;SATIR($A$1:İNDİS($A:$A;KAÇINCI("zzz";$A:$A)))/(EĞERSAY($B$2:B2;$A$1:İNDİS($A:$A;KAÇINCI("zzz";$A:$A)))=0);RASTGELEARADA(1;SATIRSAY($A$1:İNDİS($A:$A;KAÇINCI("ZZZ";$A:$A)))-SÜTUN(A:A)+1)))`