# Excel Return 4 random unique values to adjacent cells from a list of values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm writing a book of questions, and I'm trying to get excel handle much of the dirty job. I completed many things except for the last part, where I want excel to populate choices: 1 word already available in column H(H2:H13). I return it with a vlookup function. I neeed three other random unique values from rest of the word column ( H2:H13 ).
Here's what my excel looks like:
[image: Excelscrshot]

As you can see in the image, I need three random unique values for the cells K18, L18 and M18 (the red square) different from the word in J18.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The formula I gave to your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105615/excel-return-multiple-unique-values) should work with small modification.  What have you done trying to modify that to work here?

Comment: :) I fell asleep last night trying to modify that formula. Some values are OK, but for some, I get either #NUM or #VALUE errors and it also returns duplicate values, both for the value I return with VLookup and the other three returned by this formula. Here it is:
`=INDEX(($H$2:$H$13;AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW($H$2:$H$13)/COUNTIF($I$72:J72;$H$2:$H$13)=0);RANDBETWEEN(1;ROWS($H$2:$H$13)-COLUMN($H:$H)+1)))`
Somehow it doesn't check for duplicates, shows errors and I couldn't figure out why. By the way, the previous formula you gave me is working fine in another part of this file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in **H2** through **H13**, in **I2** through **I13** enter:

```
=RAND()
```

Then in **J18** through **M18** enter:

```
=INDEX($H$2:$H$13,RANK(I2,$I$2:$I$13,1)+COUNTIF($I$2:I2,I2)-1)  
=INDEX($H$2:$H$13,RANK(I3,$I$2:$I$13,1)+COUNTIF($I$2:I3,I3)-1)  
=INDEX($H$2:$H$13,RANK(I4,$I$2:$I$13,1)+COUNTIF($I$2:I4,I4)-1)  
=INDEX($H$2:$H$13,RANK(I5,$I$2:$I$13,1)+COUNTIF($I$2:I5,I5)-1)
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

1. this is the *VBA* approach
2. the "helper" **I** column is not needed
3. enter the following in a standard module:

```
Dim ary()


Sub Shuffle(InOut() As Variant)
    Dim HowMany As Long, i As Long, J As Long
    Dim tempF As Double, temp As Variant

    Hi = UBound(InOut)
    Low = LBound(InOut)
    ReDim Helper(Low To Hi) As Double
    Randomize

    For i = Low To Hi
        Helper(i) = Rnd
    Next i


    J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While J > 0
        For i = Low To Hi - J
          If Helper(i) > Helper(i + J) Then
            tempF = Helper(i)
            Helper(i) = Helper(i + J)
            Helper(i + J) = tempF
            temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = temp
          End If
        Next i
        For i = Hi - J To Low Step -1
          If Helper(i) > Helper(i + J) Then
            tempF = Helper(i)
            Helper(i) = Helper(i + J)
            Helper(i + J) = tempF
            temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = temp
          End If
        Next i
        J = J \ 2
    Loop
End Sub

Public Function Xclude(rX As Range, rng As Range) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    Dim v As Variant, N As Long, i As Long
    v = rX.Text
    N = rng.Count
    i = 1

    For Each r In rng
        v2 = r.Text
        If v <> v2 Then
            ReDim Preserve ary(1 To i)
            ary(i) = v2
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next r

    Call Shuffle(ary)

    Xclude = ary
End Function
```

Hi-light cells **K18** through **M18** and then click in the Formula Bar.  Then enter the array formula:

```
=xclude(J18,H2:H13)
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Comment: This formula does return 4 unique random values, but I need the first one to come from the Vlookup function, and then I want to use this formula to get 3 other unique random values.

Comment: I'll use this in 12 different rows. If it does the trick, why not? Thanks.

Comment: @Ugur  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Hi. First of all, thanks. I used it and it works, though it sometimes returns duplicates with the cell we exclude (there are no duplicates in H2:H13). You can see these screenshots. I keep hitting f9 until I get no red colors.
[ScreenshotsLinkImgur](http://imgur.com/gallery/mflRt)

Comment: is there a way to make this array formula work inside IFs? For example:
`=IF($L90=$S$48;Xclude($M90;adjs);IF($L90=$Y$48;Xclude($M90;nouns);IF($L90=$AH$48;Xclude($M90;Verbs))))`
Why am I asking? > I need to reference different areas(verbs, adjs or nouns) based on a cell value(L90). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another [solution done with Googledocs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rwZK31LJF8xVJMfRobLlwhVSE1pf-0zx9yakKy0f2tE/edit?usp=sharing)

It involves using JOIN, SPLIT, RANDBETWEEN, ADDRESS, ROW, INDIRECT,IF, LEFT, RIGHT, SUBSTITUTE, and REPT It's an iterative process, removing a value from a comma seperated list (separator is driven by B4. Be sure it's a character your data doesn't contain). Basically every time you choose a random value remove it from selection. So first time for 10 possibilties, second time, 9 possibilites, third time 8 and so on...

**REVISED V2:** WITH SEPARATOR char in B4 and using SUBSTITUTE even more. (reducing extra intermediary steps with IF formulae copying across columns then recombining).
**RESULTS:**
[image: RESULTS]
**FORMULAE**:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the previous responses, but I had to battle my way through the code for the result I wanted. I had coded similar structures in App Inventor using the blocks (I wish there was a blockly for all languages), so I translated my code into VBA. Here is the solution in case someone might use it:

```
Option Base 1
Function RSec(rng As Range, kactane As Integer, Optional exclude As String = "NoneX")
'rng is the source, kactane shows how many items to return, optional exclude will be excluded if supplied)


'lng holds the number of items in the supplied range
Dim lng As Integer
'listholder will hold everything in range
Dim listholder As New Collection
'chosen is the final list that will provide the randomly selected items
Dim chosen As New Collection
'Ranno is the random number for list index
Dim RanNo As Integer
'result is the array to return values to cells
Dim result() As String


'1- Add all items in range to listholder
For i = 1 To rng.Count
listholder.Add rng.Item(i).Value
Next i
'2- print listholder length for debug purposes
'Debug.Print "Listholder uzunluğu:"; listholder.Count

'set lng to listholdercount
lng = listholder.Count

'set a random number
Randomize
RanNo = Int((lng - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)

'main loop to choose kactane number of items
For k = 1 To kactane

'check if exclude parameter is present
    'if exclude parameter is not present, then choose randomly without checking
    If exclude = "NoneX" Then
        'add the randomly selected to the collection chosen
        chosen.Add listholder(RanNo)
        'remove the randomly selected from the list
        listholder.Remove (RanNo)
        'update the lng count
        lng = listholder.Count
    Else
       'if exclude parameter is present and randomly selected item is equal to exclude
        If listholder(RanNo) = exclude Then
        'decrement the k value to repeat this step and choose another item
        k = k - 1

        'if exclude parameter is present but not equal to the randomly chosen
        Else
                'seçileni chosen'a ekle
        chosen.Add listholder(RanNo)
        'orjinal listeden çıkar
        listholder.Remove (RanNo)
        'lng'yi güncelle
        lng = listholder.Count
        End If
    End If

're set to a new random number
Randomize
RanNo = Int((lng - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
Next k

'set the size of the array
ReDim result(chosen.Count)

'push everything in collection to array
For rd = 1 To chosen.Count
result(rd) = chosen(rd)
Next rd

'return result
RSec = result

End Function
```